# Ports used in async replication in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

When we set up async replication between two clusters using the cdc_stream commands, setup universe replication commands, is all the communication between the clusters done at port 5433/9042?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that async-replication between servers doesn't work on the client api ports: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/reference/configuration/default-ports/#client-apis

But uses inter-node communication ports, namely 7100 & 9100 https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/reference/configuration/default-ports/#internode-rpc-communication